# EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY env variable not available for F# Azure Functions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-container-service

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function describes a `EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONDIRECTORY` environment variable. But it's not available for F# functions. Also `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext` doesn't provide a FunctionDirectory property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample function confirms that the property does exist:

```fs
let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage, log: TraceWriter, context: ExecutionContext) =
    log.Info context.FunctionDirectory
    req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello")
```

(tested in the portal on v1 runtime)

Comment: did not compile for me.

Comment: What's your version of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions`?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (2.0)

Comment: How come? `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` is referencing `2.1.x`. Try upgrading.

Comment: that's a prerelease! https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions - that shouldn't be run in production

Comment: My naive approach is to reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` `1.0.7` which is not prerelease, and take whatever transient dependencies it has.